# List of all Permissions-Policy header keys and values?

Tags: nginx, security, http-headers, javascript, html5

**Does someone have a list of all `Permissions-Policy` header keys and values?**

What I have:

```
more_set_headers "Permissions-Policy: camera=(self), fullscreen=(*), geolocation=(self), payment=()";
```

It was somehow (old - don't use it):

```
more_set_headers "Feature-Policy: camera 'self'; fullscreen *; geolocation 'self'; payment 'none'";
```

Note that the old syntax is with semicolons and the new syntax requires commas.

Comment: Did you look at the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/permissions-policy-1/#policy-controlled-feature)? It tells you to go to https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/blob/master/features.md